# How to restart a game?

Tags: python, tkinter, restart

I'm making a game with tkinter where the player must dodge acid rain.
I'm almost done with it, I'm just needing a way of restarting the whole game after the Up key is pressed. I already made a function that's being called after rain hit the player. This function checks with an event if the up key is pressed and triggers than the restart function in which the code for restarting the game comes. All inside the Game class.
Here's the code:

```
import random
import time
from winsound import *
from tkinter import *

class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.high_file = open('HIGHSCORE.txt','r')
        self.high = self.high_file.read()
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.title('DeadlyRain')
        self.tk.resizable(0,1)
        self.tk.wm_attributes('-topmost',1)
        self.canvas = 
        Canvas(self.tk,width=400,height=500,highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.tk.update()
        self.bg = PhotoImage(file="bg.gif")
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image=self.bg,anchor='nw')
        self.score_txt = self.canvas.create_text(320,12,text='Score: 0', \
                         fill='white',font=('Fixedsys',17))
        self.high_txt = self.canvas.create_text(310,30, \
                        text='HighScore: %s' % self.high,\
                        fill='white',font=('Fixedsys',16))
        self.player_img = PhotoImage(file='player\\player0.gif')
        self.player = self.canvas.create_image(150,396, \
                                               image=self.player_img,
                                              anchor='nw')
        self.rain_img = [PhotoImage(file='rain\\rain1.gif'),
                         PhotoImage(file='rain\\rain2.gif'),
                         PhotoImage(file='rain\\rain3.gif')]
        self.images_left = [
            PhotoImage(file="player\\playerL1.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="player\\playerL2.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="player\\playerL3.gif")]
        self.images_right = [
            PhotoImage(file="player\\playerR1.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="player\\playerR2.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="player\\playerR3.gif")]
        self.current_image = 0
        self.current_image_add = 1
        self.last_time = time.time()
        self.new_high = False        
        self.player_x = 0
        self.rain_drops = []
        self.rain_count = 0
        self.points = 0
        self.speed = 2
        self.list = list(range(0,9999))
        self.needed_rain_count = 100
        self.running = True
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>',self.left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>',self.right)
    def animate(self):
        if self.player_x != 0 :
            if time.time() - self.last_time > 0.1:
                self.last_time = time.time()
                self.current_image += self.current_image_add
                if self.current_image >= 2:
                    self.current_image_add = -1
                if self.current_image <= 0:
                    self.current_image_add = 1
        if self.player_x < 0:
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.player, 
image=self.images_left[self.current_image])
        elif self.player_x > 0:
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.player, 
image=self.images_right[self.current_image])
    def score(self):
        self.points += 1
        if self.points > int(self.high):
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.high_txt, \
                                  text='HighScore: %s' % self.points)
            self.new_high = True
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.score_txt, \
                              text='Score: %s' % self.points)
        if self.points >= 20 and self.points <= 34:
            self.needed_rain_count = 80 
        elif self.points >= 35 and self.points <= 49:
            self.needed_rain_count = 60
        elif self.points >= 50 and self.points <= 64:
           self.needed_rain_count = 40
       elif self.points >= 65 and self.points <= 79:
           self.needed_rain_count = 20
    def gameover(self):
        self.running = False
        self.canvas.create_text(200,250,text='GAMEOVER')
        if self.new_high == True:
            new_high = open('HIGHSCORE.txt','w')
            new_high.write(str(self.points))
            new_high.close()
            self.high_file.close()
            self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Up>',self.restart) #restart func
                                                                   is called
        self.high_file.close()
    def restart(self,evt):
        #insert code for restarting game here
    def left(self,evt):
        self.player_x = -2
    def right(self,evt):
        self.player_x = 2
    def move(self):
        self.animate()
        self.canvas.move(self.player,self.player_x,0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.player)
        if pos[0] <= -8:
            self.player_x = 0
        elif pos[0] >= self.canvas.winfo_width() - 40:
            self.player_x = 0
        
    def rain(self):        
        if self.rain_count == self.needed_rain_count:
            for x in self.list:
                x =self.canvas.create_image(random.randint(0,501), \ 
                   0,image=random.choice(self.rain_img))
                   self.rain_drops.append(x)         
                    self.rain_count = 0
                    self.list.remove(x)
                    break
        
    def rain_fall(self,id):
        co = self.canvas.coords(id)
        if co[1] > 500:
            self.rain_drops.remove(id)
            self.canvas.delete(id)
            self.score()
        self.canvas.move(id,0,self.speed)
    
    def rain_hit(self,id):
        rpos = self.canvas.coords(id)
        ppos = self.canvas.coords(self.player)
        if rpos[1] >= ppos[1] and rpos[1] <= ppos[1]+68:
            if rpos[0] >= ppos[0] and rpos[0] <= ppos[0]+48:
                self.gameover()

    def mainloop(self):
        PlaySound("sound\\rain.wav", SND_ASYNC)
        while 1:
            if self.running == True:
                self.rain_count += 1
                self.move()
                self.rain()
                for rain in self.rain_drops:
                    self.rain_hit(rain)
                    self.rain_fall(rain)
                self.tk.update_idletasks()
                self.tk.update()            
                time.sleep(0.01)

g = Game()
g.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could juste remove the `while 1` from the mainloop method and use a boolean to keep looping. You could switch that boolean to false when the UP key is pressed and when the player is hit by the rain.

Then you can just do :

```
while 1 :
    g = Game()
    g.mainloop()
```

and your game will loop for ever.

Comment: It just creates a new blank window and throws this error at me:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP Pavilion G6\Desktop\python\DeadlyRain\DeadlyRain.py", line 147, in <module>
    g = Game()
  File "C:\Users\HP Pavilion G6\Desktop\python\DeadlyRain\DeadlyRain.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image=self.bg,anchor='nw')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2332, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2323, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage13" doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You write the `mainloop()` inside the init function not outside the init function. if you write the main loop outside the tkinter window creation part then the init function  cannot find the mainloop which is essential to define all the code inside window creation part and mainloop .

You write mainloop after `self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>',self.right)` part.